# Bootstrap datepicker is not working in angular2

Tags: angular

I integrated bootstrap date picker in my Angular2 code. But its not showing date picker.

In HTML

```
<div class="input-box sandbox-container">
  <input type="text" id="date" required>
</div>
```

In script

```
    $(function() {
  $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sandbox-container is a class, not an id

try

```
 $(function() {
  $('.sandbox-container input').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: And you have imported jQuery into your Angular project?

Comment: Yes, I added Jquery in my project

Answer (score 0):

When is your script called ?
It MUST be called after your dom is initialized. I suppose your HTML is a component template. You need to call your datepicker in ngAfterViewInit() of your component.

Note : jquery and angular2 don't work well together, i will have some trouble with binding.

Comment: I added the script in top of the index.html file in header.There is any option for integrating this?

Comment: Do you have an anguar2 component with a template ? Where is your html code ?